# Cross-Browser Solution: Have links clickable when under image

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have a header in a HTML page that contains a curve.

**My Problem:** The curve is a picture & it sits at the highest z-index. It is meant to cut off some text below it so it has the highest z-index. As a result, none of the links below the image(curve) can be clicked because the picture sits on top of them.

Heres the simple JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hE7D5/2/

[image]

**How can I get my links below the image to be clickable?**

The easiest way I know is to make the image have the css: pointer-events: none; **BUT** this doesn't work in IE & I am looking for the most Cross-Browser friendly solution.

```
<div id="headerContainer" style="position: relative; width: 100%; text-align: center; background-color: yellow;">
    <div id="header" style="width: 1100px; height: 400px; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px;">
        <ul id="navbar" style="background-color: red; width: 800px; height: 40px; float: left;"></ul>
        <a id="logo" href="www.google.com" style="background-color: red; width: 190px; height: 40px; float: right; margin-top: 15px;">Cant be Clicked</a>

        <br/>
        <div id="cutOffText">
            <p style="padding: 0; margin: 0; font-size: 200px;">ABCDEFG</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="curveOverlay" style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; background-image: url('http://i44.tinypic.com/rs8y7m.png'); background-position: center bottom; background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 1100; height: 400px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

*PS: If theres no way to make the links clickable when under the image, can you suggest a HTML layout I can use to still achieve my look but also have my navbar links clickable?*

Answer (score 0):

simply put :  you can't. not without a lot of effort. to achieve this effect, you'd need the image to be a imagemap and then make sure that it's pixel-perfect to the stuff that it's obscuring.

to be honest, this looks like a pretty bad idea, but you may have some legitimate reason to do this

EDIT :  looks like a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186323/is-it-possible-to-click-a-link-through-an-image-on-top-that-link)

Answer (score 0):

You could have your elements, that currently sit under the graphic, be on top of it with their backgrounds set to be mostly transparent. This way, the text would be above the image, whereas the background color would seem to be behind or inline with the graphic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to precisely control the layout of what's behind the image, you could duplicate that layout above the image using "empty" links with the same dimensions (which I've outlined with a dashed green line in the image below). [image]

Answer (score 0):

In your example you might be able to use [cssSandpaper](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/) to rotate the image of the *curve*.
If you slightly modify your curve the button will become totally clickable.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this working?

```
#logo {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
```